# Sending Values to variables using url

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Find my Favorite Movie!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo “<a href='localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Inception'>Inception</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Getting the following error for the above code.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'href' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\test\movie1.php on line 7

Answer (score 3):

As you can see you have a litteral mistake in

```
echo “<a href='localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Inception'>Inception</a>";
```

couse `“` != `"`

change it to:

```
echo "<a href='localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Inception'>Inception</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<a href="localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Inception">Inception</a>';
```

Should do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

You have an copy and past error try this:

```
echo "<a href='localhost/moviesite.php?favmovie=Inception'>Inception</a>";
```

You are using by misstake a wrong quote `“` instad of `"`. Often are quotes replaced wrong by some CMS like Wordpress. So you need to check double that you use the right quotes.